# How can i update my component after delete methods in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, sweetalert2, tsx

I use Sweetalert2 and react(tsx) and i don't know how to refresh my item list after delete methods.

Here is the code (i have a button that use this functions):

```
function DeleteCard(item: DataItem){
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
      icon: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
        const response = await Api.delete('api/stuff/${item.Id}')
        Swal.fire(
          'Deleted!',
          'Your file has been deleted.',
          'success'
        )
      }
    }).then(function(){
        window.location.reload(); // this is page reload, it is woking but not a good solutions
    })
}
```

I tried window.location.reload();, but not a good solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not a good solution"?

Comment: I would like to refresh my list, not the all page

Comment: One method people normally use is to mock the deletion instead of rehydrating the data, you can just select the appropriate item and delete it from the page to avoid making another request for the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive your items list from an `api`, instead of `window.location.reload()`, fetch the item list again.